# Match Jsonb array in postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a jsonb column in postgres table which will have the data like following..

```
 1. {"age": {"toage": "", "fromage": ""}, "sex": [], "hometown": [],
    "occupation": [], "destination": [], "nationality": [244, 245, 247],
    "travelpurpose": [], "currentlocation": []}


 2. {"age": {"toage": "45", "fromage": "25"}, "sex": [1, 2], "hometown":
    [386, 336, 337, 339, 389, 424, 453, 457, 471, 475, 377, 413,460,
    387, 458, 287, 341, 372, 2783], "occupation": [15, 17, 25, 27],
    "destination": [377, 413, 460, 387], "nationality": [340, 435],
    "travelpurpose": [5, 6], "currentlocation": []}

 3. {"age": {"toage": "45", "fromage": "25"}, "sex": [1, 2], "hometown":
    [386, 336, 337, 339, 389, 424, 453, 457, 471, 475, 377, 413,460,
    387, 458, 287, 341, 372, 2783], "occupation": [15, 17, 25, 27],
    "destination": [377, 413, 460, 387], "nationality": [340, 435],
    "travelpurpose": [5, 6], "currentlocation": []}

 4. {"age": {"toage": "", "fromage": ""}, "sex": [], "hometown": [],
    "occupation": [], "destination": [], "nationality": [],
    "travelpurpose": [], "currentlocation": []}
```

I need the query the arrays in the jsonb.

For that I am using following query.

```
SELECT * FROM campaign 
where target_demographics @> '{"sex": [1], "hometown": [337],"occupation":[], "destination": [], "nationality": [], "travelpurpose": [], "currentlocation": []}';
```

which will match the 2 and 3 jsonb cloumns.But what I need is it should also match 1 and 2 as well.

Meaning,it is only checking contains what I also need  is it should also return if the specified array is empty.

Is there any possible ways to do this postgres9.4????

**UPDATED:**

For that i have made a query like below to check it by each field.Is it the correct way to do it.Or is there any other Better ways to do this.

```
SELECT campaignid,target_demographics FROM campaign where ((target_demographics ::json#>>'{age,fromage}') ='' or (target_demographics ::json#>>'{age,fromage}')<='30') and ((target_demographics ::json#>>'{age,toage}') ='' or(target_demographics ::json#>>'{age,toage}')>='30') and (target_demographics @> '{"sex": []}' or target_demographics @> '{"sex": [1]}') and (target_demographics @> '{"hometown": []}' or target_demographics @> '{"hometown": [337]}') and (target_demographics @> '{"occupation": []}' or target_demographics @> '{"occupation": [25]}') and (target_demographics @> '{"destination": []}' or target_demographics @> '{"destination": [377]}') and (target_demographics @> '{"nationality": []}' or target_demographics @> '{"nationality": [244]}') and (target_demographics @> '{"travelpurpose": []}' or target_demographics @> '{"travelpurpose": [6]}') and (target_demographics @> '{"currentlocation": []}' or target_demographics @> '{"currentlocation": []}');
```